# Need to write protractor console output to txt file

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor, i want to write the content of console output to .text file? The purpose of this is further action is this text file will be consumed by different team and action will be take based on the content of the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you add more informations like how you run your protractor tests, which command do you use...etc. Seems like your issue could be solve with just some shell command not really related to protractor. You would just need to redirect the outputs of the tests to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily achieve this through the command line when protractor is called with a line like the following:

```
protractor conf.js > protractor-output.txt
```

This will create a new text file in the current directory containing all the output you would normally see in the console.

Comment: Thanks dublin, xcellent, but the thing is i want to see the output in the console output window also at the same time content should written to the file.........

Comment: you can replace ` > ` with: ` | tee `. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/731237